# PyQt5: NameError: 'QtWidget' is not defined

Tags: pyqt5

Moving Flask app from local environment to Ubuntu 14.04. Getting 'NameError: 'QtWidgets' is not defined"

Have done the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

verified this with following command:

```
apt-cache policy python3-pyqt5

        result: "python3-pyqt5:  
                    Installed: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1  
                    Candidate: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1  
                    Version table:  
                  ***5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0  
                        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages"
```

tried following command from python command line:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

got following response:

```
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

I'll admit to being relatively new to this, so it's probably something obvious to experienced folks. In any event thanks for any insights you can offer.

Comment: If you do `python3 -c "from PyQt5 import QtWidgets"`, do you get the same? What does `which python3` say?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is something simple: `QtWidgets` , i.e. non-singular

```
>>> from PyQt5.GUI import QtWidget
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.GUI'
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>>
```

Also, ensure that you're calling correct interpreter. You've installed PyQt5 for Python3, so use `python3`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt5
>>> 

$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Turns out I do use QtWidgets (plural); I errored in my question write-up.  Net-Net: I still have the problem. I'll edit the question to fix the issue you pointed out. Thanks again.

Comment: @psanc See my edit. Here's my suggestion: go back and review basics. Don't jump to GUI programming too fast. Train your attention to key details.

Comment: Yes, agree that it's good to go back and review basics (especially given my experience level).  I've double checked and am using the correct interpreter: Python 3.4.3